# VB.net Backgroundworker passing parameter and return value

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parameter-passing, return-value, backgroundworker

I need to run a report that get the summary of student's test which show passed or failed detail. When Click on the cmd_Start, it runs on Backgroundworker(I just want to run as multi-thread, and I find people suggest to use backgroundworker) for each student and pop-up a message box with result when all calculation done. I copied and edited some code on other example, but I don't know what should I put on the code I marked question mark. Other idea is welcome too.

```
  Dim Passed as int32= 0
  Dim Failed as int32 = 0
  Dim Total as int32 = 0

  Private Sub cmd_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_Start.Click
    Passed= 0
    Failed = 0
    Total = 0
    For i as int32 = 0 to ubound(StudentIDAry)
        Dim worker As New System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
        AddHandler worker.DoWork, ????? CountAverageScore(????,????, StudentIDAry(i))
        AddHandler worker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf HandleThreadCompletion
        worker.RunWorkerAsync()
    Next
    MsgBox("Total Counted: " & Total & vbcrlf & "Passed Count: " & Passed & vbcrlf & "Failed Count: " & Failed)
  End Sub

  Private Sub CountAverageScore(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs, ByVal StudentID As Long)
     Dim stroutput As String = e.Argument.ToString
     ..........
     ..........
     e.Result = stroutput
  End Sub

  Private Sub HandleThreadCompletion(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim return_value As String = e.Result.ToString
    If cint(return_value)>=50 Then
        Passed = Passed + 1
    Else
        Failed = Failed + 1
    End If
    Total = Total + 1
 End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily add arguments to an event handler, sender and e are provided by BackgroundWorker.  Since you have only one variable to pass, you can simply pass it to RunWorkerAsync and retrieve it again in the event handler with CLng(e.Argument).

Answer (score -2):

Rather than use all that code adding your own background worker, try this. It uses `Parallel.For` and runs everything inside the loop on its own thread.

The structure of a `Parallel.For` is pretty straight forward, but it is important to remember that the number that signifies the last iteration of the loop is exclusive.

For example in a regular loop `For I As Integer =0 to 100`, the will be at 100, but in a `Parallel.For` loop, the last iteration will be 99. Annoying, but that's how it is.

Your code might not run faster because of the performance overheads of multi-threading, and it might be worth checking how quick it runs in a parallel loop compared to a regular loop.

Dont forget to change my bit of code where I use `StudentStruct` to whatever object you're using to represent an individual student.

```
Private Sub cmd_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmd_Start.Click
    Passed = 0
    Failed = 0
    Total = 0
            Parallel.For(0, UBound(StudentIDAry) + 1,
                                      Sub(index As Integer)
                                          Dim studentAverage As Integer = CInt(CountAverageScore(StudentIDAry(index)))
                                          If CInt(studentAverage) >= 50 Then
                                              Passed = Passed + 1
                                          Else
                                              Failed = Failed + 1
                                          End If
                                          Total = Total + 1
                                      End Sub)
    MsgBox("Total Counted: " & Total & vbCrLf & "Passed Count: " & Passed & vbCrLf & "Failed Count: " & Failed)
End Sub


Private Function CountAverageScore(student As StudentStruct) As Single
    Dim score As Integer
    '
    '
    '
    Return score
End Function
```

Ditch all the BackgroundWorker code and just use the above